# INNER/LEFT JOIN two tables and extend result with row

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join

I have two tables which both have a row by the name "type". It looks like this:

**events:**

```
--------------------------------
|  id  |  title     |  type    |
--------------------------------
|  1   |  EventNo1  |  travel  |
|  2   |  EventNo2  |  info    |
|  3   |  EventNo3  |  travel  |
|  4   |  EventNo4  |  sport   |
|  5   |  EventNo5  |  info    |
--------------------------------
```

**types:**

```
--------------------------------
|  id  |  type    |  label     |
--------------------------------
|  1   |  travel  |  xxx #1    |
|  2   |  info    |  xxx #2    |
|  3   |  sport   |  xxx #3    |
--------------------------------
```

If "events.type" matches "types.type" I want to extend my query result with the label from types, so it looks like this:

**combined:**

```
-------------------------------------------
|  id  |  title     |  type    |  label   |
-------------------------------------------
|  1   |  EventNo1  |  travel  |  xxx #1  |
|  2   |  EventNo2  |  info    |  xxx #2  |
|  3   |  EventNo3  |  travel  |  xxx #1  |
|  4   |  EventNo4  |  sport   |  xxx #3  |
|  5   |  EventNo5  |  info    |  xxx #2  |
-------------------------------------------
```

How do I accomplish this? I assume I have to use INNER/LEFT JOIN, but the following attempt doesn't give me any rows:

```
SELECT events.id, events.title, events.type, types.id, types.type, types.label
FROM events 
INNER JOIN types
ON events.type = types.type
```

---

### UPDATE

Wow.. Turned out there wasn't a problem with the query at all. The reason it didn't return any rows was because the "types" table had some illegal characters in the label rows :)

Comment: You don't have to add types.type and types.id in select statement.

Comment: That's the exact statement I would use (maybe without some of the columns, as burak as mentioned).  The fact it's not returning rows suggests something else is at fault.  Table creation scripts may be helpful.  In general, it's usually advantageous to switch to numeric surrogate ids - for instance, it helps if you later discover a typo; you only have one row to update.  Or dealing with having other languages for the types (requires more work, but this is the start).

Comment: What you did is just destroy the first question. The first one was why my query doesnt work, and I my answer show you that query is working. This a totally different question and should be asked in a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you miss one `s` on `types.id`

**[SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0cfc0/1)**

```
SELECT events.id, events.title, events.type, types.id, types.type, types.label
FROM events 
INNER JOIN types
ON events.type = types.type
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| id |    title |   type | id |   type |  label |
|----|----------|--------|----|--------|--------|
|  1 | EventNo1 | travel |  1 | travel | xxx #1 |
|  2 | EventNo2 |   info |  2 |   info | xxx #2 |
|  3 | EventNo3 | travel |  1 | travel | xxx #1 |
|  4 | EventNo4 |  sport |  3 |  sport | xxx #3 |
|  5 | EventNo5 |   info |  2 |   info | xxx #2 |
```

Comment: Wow.. Turned out there wasn't a problem with the query at all. The reason it didn't return any rows was because the "types" table had some illegal characters in the label rows :)

Answer (score 0):

You missed (s) from type.id .It should be types.id.
Moreover,you need to remove type.id as it is not required as per ypur output.

```
SELECT events.id, events.title, events.type,  types.type, types.label FROM events  INNER JOIN types ON events.type = types.type
```

Please prefer to save id than using type as it will help in **saving disk space** and also id would be autoincrement so there is less chance of human error.

Comment: Splitting things off into separate tables doesn't always equate to saving space (or the space saved may be minimal), especially when you factor in any additional indices.  autoincrement ids also doesn't equate to less chance of human error - that would require additional support structures.  Moreover, surrogate ids increase the complexity of the system (and queries) - you need to `JOIN` on each query, which will take additional resources to execute.